# How to create a 2D Array in Haskell?

Tags: java, haskell

I'm struggling to create a 2D list in Haskell with elements are formed by their indices of row and column. I searched but did not find any solutions that can track the indices and use them to calculate the values to push in the array. The recursion traversal x:xs is not suitable for this problem. Please help. Thank you.

Function in Java:

```
    public static int[][] create2DArray(int r, int c) {
        int[][] arr = new int[r][c];
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = i + j;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Haskell:

```
create2DArray:: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
...
```

Output:

```
0 1 2                                                                                                                                                                              
1 2 3                                                                                                                                                                              
2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
create2DArray r c = [ [i+j | j<-[0..c-1]] | i<-[0..r-1] ]
```

Comment: Note that this is, as you request, a nested _list_, which is in some ways quite different from a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

In `Haskell`, if you really want an `array` similar to `Java`'s counterpart, `Data.Array` is what you want. For your example, the array can be contructed as follows:

```hs
create2DArray :: Int -> Int -> Array (Int, Int) Int
create2DArray r c = array ((0,0), (r-1,c-1)) [((i,j), i+j) | i <- [0..r-1], j <- [0..c]]
```